# Unable to run Asp.net Core 6.0 Web site hosted on IIS 10 Windows Server 2019 - getting 500 internal server error

Tags: iis-10, asp.net-core-6.0, windows-server-2019

I built ASP.net Core 6.0 Web application in Visual Studio 2022. I did publish to a local folder from Visual studio and hosted the application in IIS 10 Windows Server 2019 (This is a new VM. Enabled IIS and installed .netcore 6.0 Hosting Bundle) by creating a new application under default web site.  The application is configured to use inProcess hosting.  The application pool is set to No Managed Code. Installed necessary SSL certificate and also propogated the DNS.  When I try to access the website from the browser I get an error `This page isn’t working portal.abcd.com is currently unable to handle this request.HTTP ERROR 500`.

I set `stdoutLogEnabled="true" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout`. I do see a stdout file getting created under logs but the file is empty.

I tried many things suggested online but couldnt rectify this error. I am not sure what I am missing. Hoping someone can throw light on this issue.

[image]

Comment: Open Windows event log and see what errors have been recorded.

Comment: Try to check IIS logs and see whether you could find the requests to this site there. If you find the requests, check the sub-status code. For testing purposes, try to create an HTTP binding with a port number only with no hostname. try to visit the site and see if it shows the page.

Comment: @LexLi  the only error I see in the windows event log is  ComRuntime error.  Error message :  An unmarshaling policy check was performed when unmarshaling a custom marshaled object and the class {45FB4600-E6E8-4928-B25E-50476FF79425} was rejected.   I do not see anything related to .net.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT I looked into the IIS logs but could not find anything suspicious.   Here I am pasting the log for your reference.                                                                                #Date: 2022-10-17 22:11:11
#Fields: date time s-ip cs-method cs-uri-stem cs-uri-query s-port cs-username c-ip cs(User-Agent) cs(Referer) sc-status sc-substatus sc-win32-status time-taken
2022-10-17 22:11:11 10.7.0.4 GET / - 443 - 75.80.228.137 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/106.0.0.0+Safari/537.36 - 500

Comment: I could notice that you have created a new application under Default website. Have you modified the bindings of the default site? For testing purposes, could you try to create a new website and try to set the bindings of that newly created site? Further, Try to select your `site-> Error pages-> Edit feature settings-> select Detailed errors` and click OK. See if it shows any other information.